# Move the UIBarButton on the right side for the left side of the UINavigationBar - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm working on an app that needs to use the object UINavigationBar for design reasons. The project is fully created programmatically, nothing is created in the storyboard.

Created a UINavigationBar and two buttons, each button has an action:

- First button: Adds a UIBarButton the right side of UINavigationBar.
- Second button: Move the UIBarButton to the left side of UINavigationBar.

My problem is related to "move to the esquero side." I take something like "cut" (as the command + X) on the right and paste the left.

**What I have**:

My Screen is this:

[image]

My swift code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var frameSize: CGSize {
        get {
            return self.view.frame.size
        }
    }

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
    var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.frame.size = CGSize(width: frameSize.width, height: 64)
        navigationBar.frame.origin = CGPointZero
        navigationBar.items?.append(UINavigationItem(title: "NavBar"))

        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 50)))
        button.titleLabel!.text = "Touch Me"
        button.titleLabel!.tintColor = .blueColor()
        button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "touchMe:"))
        button.backgroundColor = .purpleColor()
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200), size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 50)))
        button2.titleLabel!.text = "Touch Me 2"
        button2.titleLabel!.tintColor = .blueColor()
        button2.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()
        button2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "touchMe2:"))
        self.view.addSubview(button2)

    }

    func action(sender: UIButton) {

        print("action")

    }

    func touchMe(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "action:")

        navigationBar.items?.first?.rightBarButtonItems?.append(barButton)

    }

    func touchMe2(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        navigationBar.items?.first?.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    }

}
```

**My question:**

**How do I move the UIBarButton on the right side for the left side of the UINavigationBar?**

Can someone help me?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you share the screen what you want?

Comment: Does it add button on right side when you tap button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following changes when you want to move button from right side to left side

```
func touchMe2(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    navigationBar.items?.first?.rightBarButtonItems?.removeFirst() // if you want to move first button.
    navigationBar.items?.first?.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

If you want to move arbitrary number you can use `removeAtIndex(index : Int)`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
    var yourButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,target:self, action:"")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = yourButton
```